# How to get the value by matching a string in an array of name-value pairs

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. I have an array of name value pairs as shown below.

```
array('1lakh'=>'100000.0','2lakh'=>'200000.0','3lakh'=>'300000.0','4lakh'=>'400000.0','5lakh'=>'500000.0','6lakh'=>'600000.0'),
```

Now I need to find whether the given string is in the array and give its value.
Suppose given string is 2lakh then I should get 200000.0 from the list. How to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('1lakh'=>'100000.0','2lakh'=>'200000.0','3lakh'=>'300000.0','4lakh'=>'400000.0','5lakh'=>'500000.0','6lakh'=>'600000.0');

echo $array['2lakh'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (array_key_exists('2lakh', $array)) {
  $value = $array['2lakh'];
}
```

or

```
$value = isset($array['2lakh']) ? $array['2lakh'] : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "2lakh";
$check = array_key_exists($string,$array);
if ($check) {
    echo $array["2lahk"];
}
```

`array_key_exists` will check if the array key is in the array specified, and then with the check you can assign the value to whatever you want.

If you want to get fancy and condense it..

```
if (array_key_exists("2lahk",$array)) echo $array["2lakh"];
```